# Show a Hidden UIImage on Click of button

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios, interface-builder

I have one button and one UIImageView in my .xib. I've checked the "hidden" value from Interface Builder. Now I want to show the Image on click of button. How to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked {

imageView.hidden = NO;

}
```

Comment: Yes , ImageView(img) is IBOutlet and In properties of ImageView(intrface builder) Name:img. But not working.
Code :
-(IBAction)switchToBarBlue
{
 img.hidden = NO;
}

Comment: Have u remember to connect the action method to your button?

Comment: Yes pls check if your connections are established properly and do ensure that the function is called.

Comment: Yes , the connection to the button and function is properly done. And also the function is being called (Checked with Pop-ups).Still not working :-(

Comment: Pls check if there are any views over this image view. you can try bringing the imageView to the front.

Comment: Pls accept the answers if it was useful for u. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)iambutton {
  imageyouwantgone.alpha = 0;
  imageyouwantinstead.alpha = 1;
}
```